# Ruby in Rails, production. Content doesn't updates on pages, but updates after press F5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, production

I've nginx and unicorn on VPS as production environment.

And when I add any model instance (article, post - anything) by a form of site, and click on an any link, that assigned page must shows this added content (list of articles or posts for example) - new added article I don't see it.

Or same situation with updating avatar/photo (I use paperclip gem for this).

But if I'll press F5 - they show immediately.

However, where is not any cached actions in controllers.

I don't now to where I must to dig...

Configs:
Nginx: http://pastebin.com/MdJq4PyP
Unicorn: http://pastebin.com/UrMuCAkB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nginx config tells browser to cache your dynamic content, which is not good. You may want to remove these 2 lines:

```
expires max;
add_header Cache-Control public;
```

Pressing F5 will force browser to bypass its own cache and go to server to load the content again.

Comment: Is it (old my conf, w/o your solution) mean, that every http request will be include response from a cache? If it's true, so it can work correct only for static sites like homepages IMHO.

Comment: Those 2 lines ask browser to cache the response data forever. So after loading the content the first time, browser doesn't even try to go to the server to get response again. It will just get the content from browser's own cache.

Comment: Thank you. I undestand this fully.